# Merge function from pandas generates more rows than sum of this two dataframes rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, dt1, and dt2, the common columns are columns named id.
I want the inner join of these two dataframes.
I am using the following code:
Number of rows in dt2 is 4347, Number of rows in dt1 is 4480

```
merger=pd.merge(dt2,dt1,on=['id'],how='inner')
```

Number of rows in merger is 10349.
What is problem I did not understand

Comment: You have duplicate 'id' in one or both dataframes, creating a cartesian join.

Comment: I have one id columns in each dataframe. If you meant this one

Comment: @Sht He means the `id` values are not unique, there are duplicates within the column.  You should only have one row per `id` in either dataframe or you're going to get more rows on the output than you started with.

Comment: Thanks, it works, there were duplicate values